# Access 2007 RunTime Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the following lines of code in a database I'm creating.

```
Dim yr As String

yr = Format(Date, "yy")
```

The line of code was copied from another database where it works fine. However in this new database  the Format line throws the error - Run-Time Error 13: Type Mismatch. I can't see what the issue is.

Comment: Is there a chance that you have redefined the symbol `Date` elsewhere in your code? What is returned if you issue a call to `Debug.Print Date` prior to evaluating your `Format` line?

Comment: @LeeMac You can't redefine `Date` as far as I know. VBA doesn't support any kind of overloading/redefining. I don't have a clue what is going on, though.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks - it was a guess that I probably should have tested before asserting. I knew that it was possible to redefine functions such as `Val` (I found out the hard way), and therefore made the same assumption about `Date`.

Comment: The main difference is that `Date` is not only a function but a core data type too, so it generates a _lot_ more compile errors if you try to call anything date. For functions, you do have contextsand you can declare them in different contexts. The fully qualified name for `Val` is `VBA.Val`, you can redeclare it in different contexts.

Comment: Maybe a broken reference in VBA-Ide -> Tools-> References? This causes `Date`to fail. Does code complie?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that @LeeMac was actually right all along, but not `Date` but `Format` is declared in the current context. Try using the full name: `yr = VBA.Format(Date, "yy")`

Comment: Or if Eric's suggestion doesn't work try `yr=Format("2018-03-15","yy")` to test if `Date`is the problem.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth your suggestion to use yr = VBA.Format(Date, "yy") worked. Thank you. It's strange though, I've been using that piece of code for years in several databases and it has always worked

Comment: I'll write up a more full answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lee Mac said, in VBA, functions can be redeclared in different contexts. These different functions can have different input parameters, and different returns. This can cause a Type Mismatch if either one of the parameters is of the wrong type, or if a parameter of the wrong type is returned. Furthermore, this can cause unexpected behaviour.

The only function that can be redeclared in the code you shared is the `Format` function, because `Date` is also a data type, and you can't declare a function with the same name as a data type from VBA.

You can solve this by using the library and name of the function:

```
yr = VBA.Format(Date, "yy")
```

Or, to be even more specific, you could use the library, class and name of the function (not necessary since the VBA library only contains a single `Format` function):

```
yr = VBA.Strings.Format(Date, "yy")
```

You can find the full name of the function, and any possible conflicts, by using the object browser (<kbd>F2</kbd>). Typing in *Format* will both reveal `VBA.Format`, and likely also another public function with that name.